# Cannot convert return expression of type 'NSManagedObject' to return type 'String?'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have built an app (my first) and it works like I want it to, but then I needed to add CoreData to it to get my events saved/fetched. I can see that my events (add information to tableview/remove information from there) gets saved as I print it, and the app is "Loaded" in "viewDidAppear".
The problem I think is that I am saving the array, not the NSobject. OR I am fetch the array, not the NSobject? I believe what I need to do is to add my array to an NSManagedObject? 
Like this:

var List:[MealsMenu] = [].
When I do this I get it to work! Thats great! BUT, I have an VC that is calling this variable in a UIPickerView, and as soon as I Add the list to NSManagedObject (MealsMenu, which is my Entity in coredatamodel) I get this error-message:

Cannot convert return expression of type 'NSManagedObject' to return type 'String?'

I have tried to google this for a few days now but can't find any solution for this in my case. Do any of you have any idea what I can do?

My Entity (MealsMenu) have an attribute called "meals" which is refer to String.

As I said, If I skip the VC where the PickerView is I get it to work! Added and Deleted events are being saved.

Here are my code:
(All places where it says "List[row]" or "List[indexPath.row]" I get this error message).

addViewController:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class addViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

var context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as!     AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

@IBOutlet weak var input: UITextField!
@IBAction func addToMenu(_ sender: Any) {
   if input != nil{
            let newMeal = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "MealsMenu",     into: context)
    newMeal.setValue(self.input.text, forKey: "meals")
            do {
                try context.save()
                print("SAVED")
            }
            catch{
                print(error)
            }
            input.text = ""
        }else{
            print("That's not a meal!")
        }
    }



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    input.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

}
```

tableViewController:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData


class tableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (List.count)

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->     UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = List[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear




    return(cell)

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle,     forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete
    {
        List.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        myTableView.reloadData()
    }

}





@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    myTableView.reloadData()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    coredataClass.saveItems()
    coredataClass.loadData()
}

}
```

ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

var List:[MealsMenu] = []


class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var monday: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var tuesday: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var wednesday: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var thursday: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var friday: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var saturday: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var sunday: UITextField!

var daysArray = [UITextField]()

let pickerView = ToolbarPickerView()

var selectedMenu : String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupDelegateForPickerView()
    setupDelegatesForTextFields()
    coredataClass.loadData()
}




func setupDelegatesForTextFields() {
    //appending textfields in an array
    daysArray += [monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday]
    //using the array to set up the delegates, inputview for pickerview and also the     inputAccessoryView for the toolbar
    for day in daysArray {
        day.delegate = self
        day.inputView = pickerView
        day.inputAccessoryView = pickerView.toolbar
    }
}

func setupDelegateForPickerView() {
    pickerView.dataSource = self
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.toolbarDelegate = self
}
}

    // Create an extension for textfield delegate

extension ViewController : UITextFieldDelegate {
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    self.pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
}
}





// Extension for pickerview and toolbar

extension ViewController : UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return List.count
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component:     Int) -> String? {

    return List[row]
}


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component:     Int) {

    // Check if the textfield isFirstResponder.
    if monday.isFirstResponder {
       monday.text = List[row]
    } else if tuesday.isFirstResponder {
        tuesday.text = List[row]
    } else if wednesday.isFirstResponder {
        wednesday.text = List[row]
    } else if thursday.isFirstResponder {
        thursday.text = List[row]
    } else if friday.isFirstResponder {
        friday.text = List[row]
    } else if saturday.isFirstResponder {
        saturday.text = List[row]
    } else if sunday.isFirstResponder {
        sunday.text = List[row]
   } else {
        //log errors
    }
}

}

extension ViewController: ToolbarPickerViewDelegate {

func didTapDone() {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func didTapCancel() {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
 }
}
```

Specific these functions/lines in "ViewController" are throwing theses errors:
Cannot convert return expression of type 'MealsMenu' to return type 'String?'

```
 func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    return List[row]
}


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    // Check if the textfield isFirstResponder.
    if monday.isFirstResponder {
       monday.text = List[row]
    } else if tuesday.isFirstResponder {
        tuesday.text = List[row]
    } else if wednesday.isFirstResponder {
        wednesday.text = List[row]
    } else if thursday.isFirstResponder {
        thursday.text = List[row]
    } else if friday.isFirstResponder {
        friday.text = List[row]
    } else if saturday.isFirstResponder {
        saturday.text = List[row]
    } else if sunday.isFirstResponder {
        sunday.text = List[row]
   } else {
        //log errors
    }
}
```

And in "tableViewController" this function is throwing a similar error:
Cannot assign value of type 'MealsMenu' to type 'String?'

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = List[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

Thanks a lot for any guidens and help!

/
Andreas

Comment: You have a `MealsMenu` object. You need to access its `.meals` property to get the string you saved

Comment: Thanks! I tried to access it by do as you said but I get this error: "Property 'meals' is not a member type of 'MealsMenu'". But it IS a member, right? I have an attribute called "meals" in the Entity "MealsMenu. thanks...

Comment: It ess that simple!! Thanks a lot! I got it work! 

Answer (score 0):

Please read the error message carefully and then have a look at you design

Your data source is an array of `MealsMenu` instances which is a subclass of `NSManagedObject` while the return value is of type `String?`.

That's what the error message says: You cannot return a `MealsMenu` instance where a string is expected

```
return List[row].meals
```

---

There are two bad practices in the data source declaration line.

1. Variable names are supposed to be named lowercased.
2. The variable name of an array is supposed to be named in plural form.

The latter would indicate clearly that the variable contains multiple items for example

```
var menus : [MealsMenu] = []
```

With this change and with splitting the line into two the error becomes more obvious

```
let menu = menus[row]
return menu.meals
```

By the way the naming `meals` is also confusing because it implies to be an array.

---

In `cellForRow` change the lines accordingly

```
let menu = menus[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel?.text = menu.meals
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback! I will have a look at this ASAP! :) thanks, as you probably already understand I’m new to this. :)